# Order a list of ip,domain and url

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a txt with some IPs,domains and urls but the list is not organized. I want to divide the IP, domain and url like that:

List before:

> 1.1.1.1
>
> domain.com
>
> 2.2.2.2
>
> https://url.com/test
>
> 3.3.3.3
>
> domain2.com

List after:

> IP
>
> 1.1.1.1
>
> 2.2.2.2
>
> 3.3.3.3
>
> DOMAIN
>
> domain.com
>
> domain2.com
>
> URL
>
> https://url.com/test

How can i do it? Thanks!

Comment: Loop through the file, use regex to determine if the line is an `ip`, `domain`, or `url`, and place each in their own list. Sort each list. Append each list together in your preferred order.

Comment: Hello JNevill thanks for your tip, but can u give me an example of code?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. It's a place to ask a specific question like "Here's my code, I'm iterating through this file and building this list of IP's I find via regex. Once built, I try to sort, but the order isn't what I want". Perhaps you are looking for http://upwork.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats what you need, you must install `validators` with the following command `pip install validators`. Hope this helps

##### Code:

```py
import validators
import re

my_dict = dict()
with open('config.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if bool(re.match(r"[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}", line)):
            my_dict.setdefault('IP', []).append(line)
        elif validators.url(line):
            my_dict.setdefault('URL', []).append(line)
        elif validators.domain(line):
            my_dict.setdefault('DOMAIN', []).append(line)

for key in my_dict.keys():
    print(key, '\n')
    for value in my_dict[key]:
        print(value , '\n')
```

##### Output:

```
IP 

1.1.1.1
 

2.2.2.2
 

3.3.3.3
 

DOMAIN 

domain.com
 

domain2.com 

URL 

https://url.com/test
```

you should also replace `config.txt` with your text file